# How is heroku's dyno implemented? (e.g. one dyno = one core CPU in AWS?)

Tags: heroku

I am studying PAAS archtecture, and found heroku's dyno looks very similar with IAAS's CPU:

- 1 dyno looks very like a 1 core CPU
- can run docker/k8s
- can show metrics like CPU usage , like 30% usage
- can scale from 1 to 10, very like virtual-machine or virtual CPU

so I want to know,

1. how does heroku implement a dyno?(e.g. is a dyno simplely equals to a docker?)
2. how do they get the metrics of a dyno?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it asks us to speculate about the inner workings of a company's proprietary service offering.

Comment: It's rediculous. "speculate about the .. of a company", is dyno a great tech? I don't care this $xxt only if it were not for preparing lessons. also it's very easy to implement this after several hours research . see my own answer.

Comment: This _is_ off-topic. Your answer is a _guess_ that doesn't answer the question you asked. Heroku is not Dokku. Please read [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/354577)

Comment: I am asking the question, you said it's speculate... I am telling the answer from the similar product, you said it's a guess. OK, you are always correct~ byebye

Answer (score -2, accepted):

1 dyno ~= 1 core cpu docker

I spent several hours read the documents about the open sourced PAAS, like dokku, and I believe this kind of container is based on docker.

1 container in PASS ~= 1 docker

so,

1 poor dyno ~= 1 core cpu 512MB mem docker

1 strong dyno ~= 16 core cpu 32G mem docker

thanks to the docker's API, you can change its config dynamically.
Also you can monitor/metric your dyno , such as: CPU /memory/network/disk usage.

You can implement your own dyno in minutes. that's it.

refer to:

https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/

https://dokku.com/